# How can I Use begins_with method on primary key in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have Table with 2 attribute id(string,primary key), value(string).
When I try follwoing KeyConditionExpression it throws **Query key condition not supported**.

```
KeyConditionExpression: "begins_with(ID, :tagIDValue)" 
                        or
KeyConditionExpression: "contains(ID, :tagIDValue)"
```

From [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231708) link I came to know we can use only EQ operations on main key. How can I achieve this

**Solution:======================================================**

I need to use begins_with or contains to filter So I went with following approach.

Table attributes: PK(partion_key, string), ID(sort key, string), value(string).

Now my primary key is framed based on PK,ID

PK will have constant value for all rows. so KeyConditionExpression will be like.

```
KeyConditionExpression: "PL = :pk  and begins_with(ID, :tagIDValue)"
```

**NOTE: But still *contains* not working with KeyConditionExpression. I think it was removed from KeyConditionExpression**

Comment: Your own "Solution" showed me the correct syntax for "PL = :pk  and begins_with(ID, :tagIDValue)." Thank you. This is not very clear in the AWS documentation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `begins_with` and `contains` only with a range key after specifying an EQ condition for the primary key.

To use EQ with the primary key you can do

```
KeyConditionExpression: "ID = :tagIDValue"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have crated primary key with partion key and range key or sort key

Comment: @Praveenkumar Please note that range key and sort key are the same. It's just that range key is old terminology from AWS. Nowadays they use the term sort key.

Comment: With Query you can do operations like >=, <=, begins_with(), or between, but you can’t do contains() or ends_with(). This is because an item collection is ordered and stored as a B-tree (c)

Answer (score 14):

I would stay away from scans at all costs, in this scenario I would create a global secondary index. The primary key on a GSI doesn't require uniqueness and you can query off of that. Storage is cheap, you can probably live with the extra keys.

Comment: Using GSI you'll still need to use `begins_with` on the sort key, won't you?

Comment: @MitchellTyson, does one need to ensure that the amount of data in the GSI not go over 10GB as that is the max size of a partition?

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with Tolbahady statement regarding `begins_with` and `contains` only workable in range key. You can use any comparison operator in any keys using method `scan`. Scan is a flexible but expensive and inefficient way of conducting dynamodb queries.

Anyways, there is a tool named, [AWS NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.settingup.html). It is little bit like MySQL Workbench. What is the good thing about it, is you can construct your table while checking against your access patterns(possible and most used queries of your application against your table).

Comment: this is a really bad advice. stay away from scans. if you ever need to do scanning (other than when debugging) you are using DDB in a wrong way. I'd even consider if DDB is the right choice over an RDBMS.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use the `begins_with` condition expression on the Hash(primary) key. It is only applicable with the `scan` method and Range(sort) key.

The other thing you can do is create a `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` with ID as the Hash key.

For Example:

```yaml
  IntentTable:
     Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
     Properties:
       BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
       KeySchema:
         - AttributeName: id
           KeyType: HASH
         - AttributeName: timestamp
           KeyType: RANGE
       AttributeDefinitions:
         - AttributeName: client
           AttributeType: S
         - AttributeName: timestamp
       GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
         - IndexName: byID
           KeySchema:
             - AttributeName: ID
               KeyType: HASH
             - AttributeName: timestamp
               KeyType: RANGE
           Projection:
             ProjectionType: ALL
```

And then now you can use the `query` using that index instead of `scan.` Avoid scan at all costs, or you will be shocked with the monthly billing.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will work on DynamoDB PartiSQL:

SELECT * FROM **TABLENAME** WHERE begins_with("**COLUMNNAME**", '**BEGINNING LETTER OR WORD**')

1. Replace with your table `TABLENAME`
2. Replace your `COLUMNNAME`
3. Replace your starting letter `BEGINNING LETTER OR WORD`

Comment: The COULUMNNAME should not be in engulfed in inverted commas or else the query does not work. correct synthax is: SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE begins_with(COLUMNNAME, 'BEGINNING LETTER OR WORD')